# In the ring $\mathbb{Z[i]}$, show that $3$ is a prime element, but $5$ is not a prime element. And show that the units are $1$, $-1$, $i$, $-i$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In the ring $\mathbb{Z[i]}$, show that $3$ is a prime element, but $5$ is not a prime element. And show that the units are $1$, $-1$, $i$, $-i$.

Which led:
Let $3|(a+bi)(c+di)$ for some $(a+bi),(c+di) \in \mathbb{Z[i]}$, so $(a+bi)(c+di)=3$. Then suppose that $3|(a+bi)$ so $a+bi=3(e+fi)$ which indicates that $a=3e$ and even there I stagnate.

Comment: 3 is real so try to write it as a product of some number by it's conjugate ! Also, about the units, use the fact that your ring is euclidean for the square of the norm :) using this, a number is prime iff its squared norm is prime in Z

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to use the norm map. We'll define $N(z) = z \overline z$ for $z \in \mathbb Z[i]$. Then $N(zw) = N(z) N(w)$ and $N(a + bi) = a^2 + b^2$, which is a natural number.

Let's first apply this to units. Suppose $z$ is a unit. Then there must be some $w$ such that $zw = 1$. Applying the norm map, we get $N(zw) = N(1) = 1$. Thus, $N(z) N(w) = 1$. Since the image of $N$ lies in the natural numbers, we must have $N(z) = N(w) = 1$. Thus, if we write $z = a + bi$ for $a, b \in \mathbb Z$, we must have $a^2 + b^2 = 1$. Then exactly one of $a^2$ and $b^2$ must be 1 and the other must be 0. This yields our 4 choices $1, -1, i, -i$, so these are all the units.

Now let's work with 3. Suppose we factor $3 = zw$ in $\mathbb Z[i]$. Then again applying the norm map, $9 = N(3) = N(z) N(w)$. To show that 3 is prime we want to conclude that $z$ or $w$ are units. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that they are not. Then as discussed in the previous paragraph, $N(z)$ and $N(w)$ cannot be 1. As $9 = 3^2$ and $N(z) N(w) = 9$, we therefore must have $N(z) = N(w) = 3$. Let's write $z = a + bi$. Then $N(z) = a^2 + b^2 = 3$. In other words, we have written 3 as the sum of two squares, but this is impossible, as the only squares that are at most 3 are 0 and 1. Hence, we have arrived at a contradiction so one of $z, w$ must be a unit. Hence, 3 is prime.

EDIT: Technically, I showed here that 3 is irreducible in this ring. However, this ring is a UFD (in fact, a Euclidean domain) so these ideas align.

As for 5, we can find an explicit factorization. Indeed, $5 = 1 + 2^2 = (1 - 2i)(1 + 2i)$. As shown above, the only units are $1,-1,i,-i$ so this is indeed a factorization of 5. Hence, it is not prime.

Comment: Very well done. +1